# Getting status 400 while using google Gmail API using service account approach

Tags: java, gmail-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

Response I'm Getting :-

```
{“status”:“400”,“schemes”:“Bearer”,“scope”:“https://mail.google.com/”}
```

I am trying to send mail using javax mail and GMAIL SMTP settings. 
    The latest Gmail API comes with auth2 approach.

I did the following steps:

```
Step1: Using the service account file i generate the access token.

Step2: Use the above generated access token for XOAUTH2 authentication for sending mail.
```

I am attaching code here

```
File 1: GoogleServiceAccountAuthentication.java helps in generating access token

File 2: GmailSMTPCheck.java helps in sending the mail
```

Please do help and let me know if i am missing any steps

```
File 1: GoogleServiceAccountAuthentication.java


public class GoogleServiceAccountAuthentication {

    private static final Logger logger =
            LogManager.getLogger(GoogleServiceAccountAuthentication.class);

    @Value("${proxy.host}")
    private String proxyHost;

    @Value("${proxy.port}")
    private int proxyPort;

    private GoogleCredentials googleCredentials;

    private void getGoogleCredentails(String jsonContent) {
        try {
            JSONObject serviceAccountKey = new JSONObject(
                    jsonContent);
            if (proxyHost != null && proxyPort > 0) {
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
                        new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
                HttpTransport httpTransport =
                        new NetHttpTransport.Builder().setProxy(proxy).build();
                HttpTransportFactory httpTransportFactory = () -> httpTransport;
                this.googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                        .fromStream(
                                IOUtils.toInputStream(serviceAccountKey.toString(), "UTF-8"),
                                httpTransportFactory)
                        .createScoped(Collections.singleton(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM));
            } else {
                // If proxy not required
                this.googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                        .fromStream(
                                IOUtils.toInputStream(serviceAccountKey.toString(), "UTF-8"))
                        .createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://mail.google.com/"));
            }
            // We are catching the exception because in BOT, user can have multiple NALP configured,
            // so one faulty NALP configuration should not stop others
        } catch (JSONException jsonexception) {
            logger.error("The serviceAccountKey content is not a valid json", jsonexception);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            logger.error("Error while creating GoogleCredentials", ie);
        }
        logger.debug("creation of googleCredentials object is successful");
    }


    public String getAccessToken(String jsonContent) throws IOException {
        getGoogleCredentails(jsonContent);
        // This will check if accesstoken is expired and refresh it
        this.googleCredentials.refreshIfExpired();
        logger.debug("Preparing to get accesstoken");
        return this.googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }

}




File 2 : GmailSMTPCheck.java


public class GmailSMTPCheck {


    private static final String SMTP_SERVER_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private static final String SMTP_SERVER_PORT = "587";
    private static final String SUBJECT = "Sending mail with Gmail SMTP and Java Mail";
    private static final String BODY = "Hi,<br><br>This is a programmatic email.";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        GmailSMTPCheck gmailSMTPCheck = new GmailSMTPCheck();

        GoogleServiceAccountAuthentication googleServiceAccountAuthentication =
                new GoogleServiceAccountAuthentication();

        JSONObject jsonContent = new JSONObject(
                "<<ServiceAccount_JSON_STRING>>");
        final String FROM_USER_EMAIL = "<<Enter gmail id>>";
        final String FROM_USER_FULLNAME = "<<Enter gmail id>>";
        final String FROM_USER_ACCESSTOKEN =
                googleServiceAccountAuthentication.getAccessToken(jsonContent.toString());
        System.out.println("The accesstoken is : " + FROM_USER_ACCESSTOKEN);
        final String TO_USER_EMAIL = "<<Enter To user gmail id>>";


        gmailSMTPCheck.sendMail(SMTP_SERVER_HOST, SMTP_SERVER_PORT, FROM_USER_EMAIL,
                FROM_USER_ACCESSTOKEN, FROM_USER_EMAIL, FROM_USER_FULLNAME, TO_USER_EMAIL, SUBJECT,
                BODY);
    }


    void sendMail(String smtpServerHost, String smtpServerPort, String smtpUserName,
            String smtpUserAccessToken, String fromUserEmail, String fromUserFullName,
            String toEmail, String subject, String body) {
        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpServerPort);
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
            props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms.oauth2.oauthToken", smtpUserAccessToken);
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
            session.setDebug(true);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromUserEmail, fromUserFullName));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setContent(body, "text/html");

            SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, null);
            transport.connect(smtpServerHost, smtpUserName, null);
            /*
             * transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(BASE64EncoderStream.encode(
             * String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", smtpUserName, smtpUserAccessToken)
             * .getBytes())),
             * 235);
             */


            byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", smtpUserName,
                    smtpUserAccessToken).getBytes();
            response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

            transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response),
                    235);



            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.FATAL, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            System.out.println("the message" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

After executing my code I always get below exception message (Base 64 decoded : {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"})
```

Output:
    The accesstoken is : <>
    DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.0
    DEBUG SMTP: enable SASL
    DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
    DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
    220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 20sm15725767pfh.72 - gsmtp
    DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

```
    EHLO N-20HEPF0V78PV.mshome.net
    250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [131.228.66.30]
    250-SIZE 35882577
    250-8BITMIME
    250-STARTTLS
    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    250-PIPELINING
    250-CHUNKING
    250 SMTPUTF8
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
    STARTTLS
    220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
    EHLO N-20HEPF0V78PV.mshome.net
    250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [131.228.66.30]
    250-SIZE 35882577
    250-8BITMIME
    250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    250-PIPELINING
    250-CHUNKING
    250 SMTPUTF8
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
    DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
    AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1icG1tYWlsY2hlY2tAYnBtbWFpbGNoZWNrLmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tAWF1dGg9QmVhcmVyIHlhMjkuYy5FbGwtWQPTQi05V1Zyd1pmYVBGbTJFQzdub2xwdE1XVkVGSFhMX3liNWFhMnYwTG9vODEzTDNhTHVrakg1ZE9xY2lnUW9zNVVCZ3AxWjVEWjhMOUxPNVptOUk5MXQ5YllkUTJxV0dfNFJObHFnUVdOa3BVZDFCclpfYzRvdwEB
    334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQQWOMmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
    12:15:13.440 [main] FATAL com.motive.camunda.mail.GmailSMTPCheck - 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==

    javax.mail.MessagingException: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2309) ~[javax.mail-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
        at com.motive.camunda.mail.GmailSMTPCheck.sendMail(GmailSMTPCheck.java:86) [classes/:?]
        at com.motive.camunda.mail.GmailSMTPCheck.main(GmailSMTPCheck.java:45) [classes/:?]
    the message334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
```

Comment: Where you following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)? if not, I suggest you take a look because it should be able to help you. Aside from that, I believe you have posted your tokens in the question, please deactivate them or you risk access to them.

Comment: Thanks, Access token for google is valid for an hour only, however as you suggest i have removed them.   Regarding the tutorial, you shared it talks about the Oauth Client ID approach not service account key approach. Also once i get the access token i want to use javax mail settings (SMTP XOAUTH2) to send mail.